# HTML with id's construct dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an html page with a `div` that has a bootstrap button to collapse/expand a table. I want to click on it to toggle collpase/expand.

I am inspired by this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtowle/Vq6gt/1/).

The javascript is

```
    $('.meu-painel-colapsar').on('click', function () {
        var id1 = $('.meu-painel-colapsar').attr('id');
        var id2 = $('.colapsar-competencias').attr('id');
         alert(id1);
        $('#' + id2 + ' .colapsar-competencias').collapse('toggle');
    });
```

And the html is

```
@foreach($dados as $dimensaoNome => $dimensao)
        <div class="panel panel-{{ $cores[$dimensaoNome] }} meu-painel-colapsar" id="accordion-{{ $dimensao->id }}">

                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"
                                id="dimensao_{{ $dimensao->id }}"
                                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span> veja os resultados
                        </button>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                @foreach($dimensao->competencias as $competenciaNome => $competencia)

                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6"><h4 class="competencia-head">{{ $competenciaNome }}</h4></div>
                            <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-top:8px;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse colapsar-competencias" id="competencia-{{ $competencia->id }}">
                        <table class="table table-condensed">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Situação atual</th>
                                <th class="col-md-6">Oportunidades identificadas</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p>{{ $competencia->nivel->texto }}</p>                                        
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        {!! $competencia->recomendacao !!}
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
@endforeach
```

The id's `accordion-{{ $dimensao->id }}` and `competencia-{{ $competencia->id }}` are generated with the two `foreach's`.

The problem is that the javascript code only gets the first id's of `accordion-{{ $dimensao->id }}` and `competencia-{{ $competencia->id }}`.

I'm struggling with this for hours without success. How can I get this id's correctly when I click the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding right, you are much better off not using `id`s at all and just relying on `class`es. Use `$(this).find(...)` to only find `.colapsar-competencias` elements that are *inside* the clicked element.

```
$('.meu-painel-colapsar').on('click', function () {
    $(this).find('.colapsar-competencias').collapse('toggle');
});
```

Comment: Exactly that @Nerdwood. Only inexperience with javascript. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Glad we could help you out!  :)  Make sure you mark an accepted answer to help out others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Vq6gt/120/

```
 $('#accordion .panel-collapse',this).collapse('toggle');
```